# Evaluating an integral by parts.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the following integral.

$$ \int x^2 e^x\ dx $$

What i have tried :

$ f^{'}(x) = e^x , f(x) = e^x , g(x) = x^2$

$$ \int x^2 e^x\ dx = e^x\ x^2 - \int e^x\ 2x\ dx $$

$ f^{'}(x) = e^x , f(x) = e^x , g(x) = 2x $

$$ \int x^2 e^x\ dx = e^x\ x^2 - e^x\ 2x - \int e^x\ x\ dx $$

$ f^{'}(x) = e^x , f(x) = e^x , g(x) = x $

$$ \int x^2 e^x\ dx = e^x\ x^2 - e^x\ 2x - x\ e^x - \int e^x \ dx $$

$$ \int x^2 e^x\ dx = e^x\ x^2 - e^x\ 2x - x\ e^x - e^x + C $$

The answer in the book is $ x^2e^x-2xe^x+2e^x+C $

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Note that integration by parts is essentially the product rule for differentiation in integral form. $\frac d{dx} x^2e^x = 2xe^x+x^2e^x$, and $\frac d{dx} xe^x=e^x+xe^x$. Integrate these two expressions with respect to $x$ and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your third line,

$$ \int x^2 e^x\ dx = e^x\ x^2 - e^x\ 2x - \int e^x\ x\ dx $$

you should have:

$$\int x^2 e^x\ dx = e^x\ x^2 -\Big(e^x\ 2x - \int 2e^x\, dx\Big)$$

Then, integrating on the right gives and distributing the negative gives us $$x^2e^x - 2xe^x + 2e^x$$

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome!